# Inject A Spring bean into AspectJ with additional pointcuts

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a spring boot project which already uses Spring AOP. For a new feature there is requirement to use `cflow` pointcut, hence AspectJ has to be integrated.

I am successfully able to Compile Time Weave aspect into my project and can see the aspect running. I know loadtime weaving should be used when the project has lombok but i manage to run it using the following [blog](https://palesz.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/howto-maven-lombok-and-aspectj-together/).

Here is the plugin in pom.xml for compile time weaving.

```xml
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources/>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                            <weaveDirectories>
                                <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                            </weaveDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources/>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                            <weaveDirectories>
                                <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</weaveDirectory>
                            </weaveDirectories>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The role of the aspect is to query a database with intercepted jointpoint. For this I am trying to inject the Spring bean annotated with `@Repository` into the aspect. As aspect is not a spring component I can not @Autowire repository in aspect class.

Repository Class

```java
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, String> {
}
```

Aspect Class

```java
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class SampleAspect {
}
```

Code already tried is

1. Making the aspect a spring component using @Configurable annotation over Aspect . Not working.

```java
@Aspect
@Configurable
@Slf4j
public class SampleAspect {
}
```

2. Creating a bean of Aspect using aspectOf function and setting the repository bean in it. Not working.

```java
    @Bean
    public SampleAspect sampleAspect(){
        SampleAspect sampleAspect = Aspects.aspectOf(SampleAspect.class);
        sampleAspect.setRepository(sampleRepository);
        return sampleAspect;
    }
```

In both of the above steps I am getting the error unsupported jointpoint cflow.

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'cflow'
```

Am I missing something here ? I need to inject a bean into plain old aspectj.

Comment: Why are you not accepting my correct answer to your original question? You can always ask new questions, if you have follow-up issues.

Comment: Hi Kriegaex , I am going through some internal validation and will either accept your answer or post an answer myself for the problem in coming week.

Comment: Six weeks of internal validation, and you still don't know that my answer is correct? Interesting. Probably, your problem was not so important anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately it took more time than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the POJO class you want to `@Autowire` a dependency into `@Configurable` is correct, also if that class happens to be a native AspectJ aspect. Making the native aspect a `@Bean` or a `@Component` is, however, a wrong and counter-productive approach, because that registers the aspect a second time as a Spring AOP aspect, which also explains the `UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException ... cflow` problem.

Missing in this picture is the information that for `@Configurable`, to work, you need `AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect` from **`spring-aspects` on the classpath.** This is true both for the load-time and compile-time weaving scenarios. I.e., you want something like this in your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In the AspectJ Maven Plugin configuration, you then also need to declare `spring-aspects` as an aspect library:

```xml
<aspectLibraries>
  <aspectLibrary>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  </aspectLibrary>
</aspectLibraries>
```

For more details, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71620434/1082681).

Slightly off topic: I find the approach to use Maven Compiler and AspectJ Maven within a single module in subsequent phases, working on the same output directory, questionable, even though in your case it seems to work. I recommend to build an unwoven module version with Maven Compiler and Lombok in module A and then in module B weave aspects into the classes from A. All other modules should depend on B and not the intermediary A. In order to avoid A to be a transitive dependency, having the same classes in two different versions on the classpath, probably it makes sense to give A `provided` scope when declaring it a dependency of B.

Comment: If i run a mvn clean install multiple times it is able to pickup cflow, i guess it is then able to compile time weave using aspectj and other time spring aop is getting picked up. I have multiple plugins like aspectj-maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin etc. Do you see these as an issue for mixup ?

Comment: Also not able to get your suggestion for separating out the modules. I have a multimodule project with modules like app, api, common, domain , services. All modules use lombok. The service module contains aspect.Service module is dependency in app module. I have the aspect plugin in the parent pom outside all modules. Can you please put your suggestion based on following structure for me to verify

Comment: SO is not a discussion forum. I answered your original question already, and correctly too, I think. I tried. So, I would appreciate you accepting and upvoting the question. If then you have more questions, create new ones and always add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem. I cannot debug prose, only code.